# How do I configure multiple JPA data sources using Spring @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dependency-injection

I am trying to configure multiple JPA entity/transaction managers within the same application context using Spring's `@Configuration` class.

When the context loads, Spring is having difficulties auto-wiring the beans because they implement the same interfaces.

Unfortunately, I'm using legacy code so I can't auto-wire the beans directly and use the `@Qualifier` annotations, which is why I'm trying to do it using the configuration class.

Within a `@Bean` declaration, is there any way to qualify which bean should be injected? I thought that using a direct method call would be enough, but it typically results in errors such as

> NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but
>   found 4

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do below:

```
@Configuration    
public class ApplicationConfig {

@Bean(name = "transactionManager1")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager1() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory1());
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory1")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory1() {
    ...
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource1());
    ...
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.test1")
public JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean1() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource(jndiObjectFactoryBean1().getJndiName());
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory2());
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory2")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory2() {
    ...
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource2());
    ...
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.test2")
public JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean2() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource(jndiObjectFactoryBean2().getJndiName());
}
```

I suppose I could try to inject the beans directly via the Spring context's getBean() method, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

I'm not too familiar with the @Primary annotation, but based on what I've read I don't know how spring would autowire the secondary data source in this case since it looks like it would always pick the beans with @Primary first.

Comment: What do the `@Autowired` injection sites look like? Are they all just `DataSource` fields? You 100% cannot change them?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the injection sites to add qualifiers, then you're going to have to create a delegating `DataSource` based on some logic (which you haven't detailed in the question).

Something like this.

```
@Primary @Bean
public DelegatingDataSource delegatingDataSource(List<DataSource> sources) {
    return new DelegatingDataSource() {
        @Override
        public DataSource getTargetDataSource() {
            // decide which dataSource to delegate to
            return sources.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

I've used [`DelegatingDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html), but that may not be able to provide what you need. You may need to get more advanced with some kind of interceptor/aspect to get details of the caller on which to base the DataSource selection.

However it's implemented, you need to specify a `@Primary` bean and use it as a proxy.